# Break long word in a div when word-wrap:break-word; fails

Tags: css

I want the word in the third column to break why won't it?

http://jsfiddle.net/madprops/6S7Rn/1/

Comment: I see a jumbled mess of letters, and no "yeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee".

Comment: The code here is based on my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6708816/3-columns-center-column-fixed-sides-fill-parents. It's not finished, I was waiting for the same OP to respond to my question..

Comment: @minitech: You need the "Result" pane to be around 900px wide. Or, see: http://jsfiddle.net/madprops/6S7Rn/1/show/

Comment: @thirtydot oh sorry I didn't see a notification about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're after? http://jsfiddle.net/kuN4T/

I used a tiny snippet of jQuery-powered JavaScript to handle the right column:

```
var $e = $('#rightBlockReal'),
    $o = $('#rightblockfake');

$(window).resize(function() {
    $e.width($o.width());
}).resize();
```

Comment: by the way, do you know if it will be possible to make the content inside the right div scrollable? Like having it's own scroll apart?

Comment: Here's an example with `overflow-y: auto`: http://jsfiddle.net/kuN4T/1/. `overflow`/`overflow-x`/`overflow-y` with a value of either `auto`/`scroll` is the solution, depending on what you want.